# Keeping the Screen Turned off While Getting Inputs

Tags: linux, gpu, x-windows, xrandr, dpms

I need to run a set of (**graphical**) **benchmarks** with the screen **disabled**. The following command did **not** work:

```
xset dpms force off
```

Because any keyboard/mouse **input** would **re-enable** the screen. The **other** option was the following:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --off
```

This turns off the screen for a **second**, then, causes the following **segmentation fault**:

```
gnome-shell[25737]: segfault at 8 ip 00007f3d02ef9210 sp 00007ffeee4e1fd8 error 4 in libmutter-2.so.0.0.0[7f3d02e99000+156000]
```

How can the problem be **solved**? Is there any **other** user/kernel level alternative?

---

**UPDATE:**

The output for `xinput --list` is shown below:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USBest Technology SiS HID Touch Controller    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Wireless Radio Control               id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

---

P.S.: This question is also asked in the [Unix StackExchange Website](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/754782/348219) and [Xorg Mailing List](https://lists.x.org/archives/xorg/2023-August/061427.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can disable mouse and keyboard input using `xinput --list` to list the input devices by name and id, then using `xinput --disable device-or-id` for each of the real mouse and keyboard devices. To reverse use `--enable`.

Alternatively, you can use `sudo evtest --grab /dev/input/eventN &` where N is the number of the input device. The grab lasts until the process is interrupted.

---

Another thing to try is setting the screen to stay on in the Xserver, then use `ddccontrol` to talk directly to the monitor over the DDC I2C bus. If the monitor is recognised, you can give a command to turn it off. Presumably, the Xserver will not try to turn it on if it assumes it is still on.

Comment: I **need** to receive the inputs. Because the benchmarks are **interactive** applications. The inputs are **recorded and replayed** using `Cnee` (in the form of **mouse/keyboard** events) even when the screen is **disabled**.

Comment: `xinput --list` should show you that there are separate `XTEST` pointer and keyboard; these are used by playback tools like cnee.

Comment: When I use the **first** deactivation command (i.e., `xset dpms...`), using `Cnee` will also **reactivate** the screen. Do you mean that I should **disable** the input types used by `Cnee` and this will **prevent** screen re-activation? Could you **elaborate** further? I have **updated** the question to **include** the `xinput --list` command **output**.

Comment: I do **not** understand how using `XTEST` can help **avoid** screen reactivation. Also even if this is **true**, based on the traces, `Cnee` is **not** using `XTEST` slave devices. How can I **force** `Cnee` to use `XTEST` devices?

Comment: No, you are right. I dont see how to avoid reactivation if there is interactive input, even XTEST. I thought you were wanting to avoid unintentional input, from people jogging the mouse etc. Perhaps you can try the `ddccontrol` hack I also mentioned.